# Expectation of hitting time for simple symmetric random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, random-walk, stopping-times

Assume there is a simple symmetric random walk
$$S_n=X_1+...+X_n,\quad S_0=0$$
where $\mathbb P(X_i=\pm 1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Define $T=\inf\{n:S_n=1\}$. How to compute $\mathbb E(T)$?

---

My idea: if $\mathbb E(T)<\infty$ then
$$\mathbb E(S_T)=\mathbb E(T)\mathbb E(X_i)$$
where $\mathbb E(S_T)=1$, $\mathbb E(X_i)=0$  so there is a contradiction.

Therefore, $\mathbb E(T)=\infty$.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: No. Next question?

Comment: @Did oh,I just want to verify my proof,the conclusion is so strange.

Comment: What is "so strange" here?

Comment: to add, $S_n$ is a Markov Chain (symmetric random walk) on the integers. It is null recurrent. The proof you just gave verifies it cannot be positively recurrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct: the expected value of this hitting time is infinite.

To add, $S_n$ is a Markov Chain (symmetric random walk) on the integers. It is null recurrent. The proof you just gave verifies it cannot be positively recurrent. -- [Lost1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085399/expectation-of-hitting-time-for-simple-symmetric-random-walk#comment2216350_1085399)