# Prove that expectation of a stopping time is (in)finite

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, martingales, random-walk, stopping-times

Let $S_n$ be a simple random walk, with $S_0 = 0$ and $S_n = \sum_{i=1} ^{n} X_i$, where $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and the $X_i$ i.i.d.

Define the stopping time $T := \inf \{n \geq 0 : S_n \in \{a,b\} \}$, with $a <0 < b$.

How can I show whether $E[T] < \infty$ ?

I know that random walk in dimension 1 is recurrent, so the hitting times of $a$ and $b$ are finite, but I don't see how I can use this to show $E[T] < \infty$.

Comment: Hint: Can you show that $$P(T>n+b-a\mid T>n)\leqslant1-\frac1{2^{b-a}}$$ for every $n$?

Comment: @Did $P(T>n+b-a\mid T>n) = \frac{P(T>n+b-a) P(T>n)}{P(T>n)} = P(T>n+b-a) = 1- P(T \leq n+b-a) = 1- \frac{1}{2^{n+b-a}} \leqslant1-\frac1{2^{b-a}}$

Comment: No, already the first equality is wrong.

Comment: Then let's write $$P(T>n+b-a\mid T>n) = \frac{P(T>n+b-a ,T>n)}{P(T>n)} =  \frac{P(T>n+b-a)}{P(T>n)}  = \frac{1 - P(T \leq n+b-a)}{1 - P(T \leq n)} = \frac{1- \frac{1}{2^{n+b-a}}}{1- \frac{1}{2^{n}}}$$

Comment: ?? But $P(T\leqslant n+b-a)\ne\frac1{2^{n+b-a}}$ and $P(T\leqslant n)\ne\frac1{2^n}$ in general, right? So what are you talking about?

Comment: I had the assumption that $T$ has a geometrical distribution.

Comment: First, geometric distributions are not such that $P(T\leqslant n)=\frac1{2^n}$ (note that the LHS is nondecreasing while the RHS is decreasing). Second, in your case, the distribution of $T$ is not geometric. Consequence: you will have to **think** about the model, not only to (mis)apply some ready-made formulas...

Comment: @clubkli If you know about martingales and the optional stopping theorem, there is also the possibility to solve this problem using martingale theory.

Comment: @saz That is what I am learning now. But in the optional stopping theorem they already consider that the expectation is finite or bounded.

Comment: Can we use similar methods to show that $\mathbb{E}[S_T]=0$?

Answer (score 7):

**Hints:**

1. Show that $S_n^2 -n$ is a martingale.
2. Apply the optional stopping theorem to the bounded stopping time $T \wedge n$ to conclude that $$\mathbb{E}(T \wedge n) = \mathbb{E}(S_{n \wedge T}^2)$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. Show that $|S_{n \wedge T}| \leq  M:=\max\{|a|,|b|\}+1$ to conclude that $$\mathbb{E}(T \wedge n) \leq M^2.$$
4. Apply the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: I hope reviving this very old question is possible. If we are in a situation where $p\neq q$, this approach seems to fail. What other approach would be possible in that case?

Comment: @S.Crim If $p \neq q$, then $M_n := S_n - n(p-q)$ is a martingale, and using a very similar reasoning as above, you can show that $$(p-q) \mathbb{E}(T \wedge n) \leq \max\{|a|,|b|\};$$ it just remains to apply the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll be back if I get stuck somewhere else. Do you also happen to know why the proof in the question in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1085399/537747 is valid? How come it is allowed to apply Wald's identity here? Isn't the stopping time dependent on the sequence?

Comment: I'm not sure how the commenting works here but perhaps you didn't see my comment because I forgot to tag you. Edit: hm tagging with @ doesn't seem to work anyway

Comment: @S.Crim That's correct, if you don't ping me I don't get a notification. What do you mean by "stopping time dependent on the sequence"? Have you ever seen a (non-trivial) stopping time which does not depend on the sequence?

Comment: I haven't, thats why this: $\mathbb{E}(S_T)=\mathbb{E}(T)\mathbb{E}(X_i)$ confuses me alot. Why is it allowed to write this if the stopping time is dependent on the sequence?

Comment: @S.Crim Search for Wald's identities/Wald's equation (google, wikipedia, whatever you like)

Comment: I have and I am familiar with it. But that identity clearly states that the $T$ in this case would have to be independent of the sequence, right? Unless I'm completely misunderstanding.

Comment: @S.Crim No, a stopping time being independent of the sequence simply doesn't make sense. It seems that you are indeed misunderstanding certain things..

Comment: Alright, let me cite Wikipedia. "Let $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real-valued, independent and identically distributed random variables and let $N$ be a nonnegative integer-value random variable that is independent of the sequence $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Suppose that $N$ and the $X_{n}$ have finite expectations. Then: $\mathbb{E}[X_{1}+\dots+X_{N}]=\mathbb{E}[N]\mathbb{E}[X_{1}]$." I understand that a stopping time being independent of the sequence is nonsense but here they clearly state independence of the $N$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @S.Crim This is one version of Wald's equation but not the one which you need (as wikipedia says this is the "basic version"). You can either read the next 2 Sections on Wikipeda or e.g. take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2237301/36150

Comment: I'll get to it. Thank you for your time and patience!