# Random Walk and Martingal

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, random-walk

Hi Guys I am trying to solve this exercice but I don't seem how to do that. Can anyone help me please?

On a probability space $(Ω, \mathcal{A}, P)$ a sequence $(X_n)_{n∈\Bbb{N}}$ of i.i.d random variables with values in the set {$-1, 0, 1$} , equally distributed on this three elemental set. Let $S = (S_n)_{n∈\Bbb{N}_0}$ with $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k $ its corresponding Random Walk.

Further $c ∈ \Bbb{N}$ and $T_c :=$ inf{$n ∈ \Bbb{N}_0| S_n ∈ ${$-c, 2c$}} .

(a) Find b ∈ R so that ($S^2_n - bn)_{n∈\Bbb{N}_0}$ is a martingale relating to the filtration
$\mathcal{F} = (\mathcal{F}_n)_{n∈\Bbb{N}_0}$ with $\mathcal{F}_n = σ(X_k : k ∈ [n])$ . The proof is needed

(b) Show $E[T_c] < ∞.$

(c) Calculate $P[T_c < ∞, S_{T_c} = -c]$ and $P[T_c < ∞, S_{T_c} = 2c]$.

(d) Calculate $E[T_c]$.}

Comment: Welcome to the forum. When you ask a question it is always better to write what you understand about the problem and what you tried. For example, the first part of your question shouldn't be too difficult, you just have to evaluate $\mathbb{E}[S_n^2-bn|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]$ and check for which $b$ it will be equal to $S_{n-1}^2-b(n-1)$. Did you try to do it?

Comment: Hi Mark Thank you for your comment. You mean evaluate the Martingale conditions right?

Comment: Yes, you need to check when $\mathbb{E}[S_n^2-bn|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]=S_{n-1}^2-b(n-1)$ holds. It's all about using the properties of conditional expectation. Hint: write $S_n^2=(S_{n-1}+X_n)^2$.

Comment: @Mark so writing  $ \mathbb{E}[S_n^2-bn|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]= \mathbb{E}[(S_^2{n-1}-2S_{n-1}X_n + X^2_n-bn|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}] = \mathbb{E}[S^2_{n-1}|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}] - \mathbb{E}[2S_{n-1}X_n|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}] - \mathbb{E}[X^2_n|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}] - b \mathbb{E}[n|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}] $

Comment: but how to proceed then?

Comment: I wrote an answer for the first part. For the second part, you might take a look at the following question, which is not the same, but a very similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986723/prove-that-expectation-of-a-stopping-time-is-infinite

Answer (score 0):

I'll write an answer for the first part.

$\mathbb{E}[S_n^2-bn|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]=\mathbb{E}[(S_{n-1}^2+X_n)^2-bn|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]=\mathbb{E}[(S_{n-1}+X_n)^2|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]-bn=$

$=\mathbb{E}[S_{n-1}^2|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]+\mathbb{E}[2S_{n-1}X_n|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]+\mathbb{E}[X_n^2|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]-bn$

Now we just have to evaluate all conditional expectations. Note that $S_{n-1}^2$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F_{n-1}}$ and hence $\mathbb{E}[S_{n-1}^2|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]=S_{n-1}^2$. Also, $X_n^2$ is independent of $\mathcal{F_{n-1}}$ and so $\mathbb{E}[X_n^2|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]=\mathbb{E}[X_n^2]=\frac{2}{3}$. Finally, note that $2S_{n-1}$ is a bounded random variable which is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F_{n-1}}$, and so:

$\mathbb{E}[2S_{n-1}X_n|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]=2S_{n-1}\mathbb{E}[X_n|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]=2S_{n-1}\mathbb{E}[X_n]=0$

Combining all of these, we get:

$\mathbb{E}[S_n^2-bn|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]=S_{n-1}^2+\frac{2}{3}-bn$

And this is equal to $S_{n-1}^2-b(n-1)$ when $b=\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the answer. the example you mentioned for the second part is a little bit complicated

Comment: @ToInfinity The process $S_{n\wedge T}^2-\frac{2}{3} n\wedge T$ is also a martingale. Hence $\mathbb{E}[S_{n\wedge T}^2-\frac{2}{3} n\wedge T]=\mathbb{E}[S_{0\wedge T}^2-\frac{2}{3} 0\wedge T]=0$. This implies $\mathbb{E}[S_{n\wedge T}^2]=\frac{2}{3}\mathbb{E}[n\wedge T]$. Now, we have $|S_{n\wedge T}|\leq 2c$, because before time $T$ we are always between $-c$ and $2c$. Thus $\mathbb{E}[n\wedge T]\leq\frac{3}{2} (2c)^2$ for all $n$. And now use the monotone convergence theorem (obviously $n\wedge T\to T$ monotonically) to conclude $\mathbb{E}[T]\leq\frac{3}{2} (2c)^2<\infty$.

Comment: can you explain more please? I know that is simple but I really can't understand your comment

Comment: What part is unclear? I assume you know that if $Y_n$ is a martingale then $Y_{n\wedge T}$ is a martingale as well? And that the expectation of all the elements have to be the same, so in particular $\mathbb{E}[Y_n]=\mathbb{E}[Y_0]$ for all $n$? This is what I used in the first part of my comment with $Y_n=S_n^2-\frac{2}{3}n$. Since expectation is linear it follows that $\mathbb{E}[S_{n\wedge T}^2]=\frac{2}{3}\mathbb{E}[n\wedge T]$. Is it clear up to this point?

Comment: yes thank you. it took me a bit time to understand it . I am still struggling . Can you please complete the last two questions please?

Comment: @ToInfinity For the third part, note that $(S_n)$ itself is a martingale. By the optional stopping theorem (can you see why it can be used here?) it follows that $0=\mathbb{E}[S_0]=\mathbb{E}[S_T]=-c\times\mathbb{P}(S_T=-c)+2c\times\mathbb{P}(S_T=2c)$. Also, since $\mathbb{E}[T]<\infty$, it follows that $\mathbb{P}(T<\infty)=1$. Hence $\mathbb{P}(S_T=-c)+\mathbb{P}(S_T=2c)=1$. So we have two equations with two variables, just solve this system to find $\mathbb{P}(S_T=-c)$ and $\mathbb{P}(S_T=2c)$.

Comment: @ToInfinity Finally, the fourth part. Since $T<\infty$ almost surely we have $S_{n\wedge T}^2\to S_T^2$ almost surely, and by the dominated convergence theorem it follows that $\mathbb{E}[S_{n\wedge T}^2]=\mathbb{E}[S_T^2]$. And now we return to the equation $\mathbb{E}[S_{n\wedge T}^2]=\frac{2}{3}\mathbb{E}[n\wedge T]$. Take $n\to\infty$ on both sides to get $\mathbb{E}[S_T^2]=\frac{2}{3}\mathbb{E}[T]$. From the third part we know the distribution of $S_T$, so you can easily compute $\mathbb{E}[S_T^2]$.

Comment: Why is S_n itself a martingale? you used here the optional stopping theorem because T is bounded? can you please detail the answer

Comment: @ToInfinity The partial sums of independent random variables with expectation $0$ is always a martingale, this is easy to check. Actually, this is the standard example of martingales. As for why we could use the optional stopping theorem, this is because $\mathbb{E}[T]<\infty$ and the differences $|S_n-S_{n-1}|$ are almost surely bounded by $1$. By the OST it follows that $\mathbb{E}[S_0]=\mathbb{E}[S_T]$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113869/discussion-between-toinfinity-and-mark).